# Problem with permission

Tags: server, permissions, docker, sftp

I have installed an SFTP Server on docker, there I want to share a folder named SFTP. 
The SFTP Folder has UID and GID 1000:1000 and I stated the SFTP Server also with ID 1000:100 and the folder has the permission drwxrwxrwx.

But when I want to access the SFTP Server I can't see folders and data in it and can create new folders, always saying, Location is not usable.

I don't understand what I did wrong. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post your sftp configuration file? Is your folder under the `chroot` path?